# Correct BIOS setting to install Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, bios, fresh-install

what's the correct BIOS settings to fresh-install Win 7 on? Also, should I use GPT or MBR partition? Here are some pics of my BIOS:

[image]

[image]

[image]

On the first one, at the SATA Controller Mode, should I use Compatible or AHCI?

The Notebook is a Lenovo G500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely AHCI

Windows 7  32 bit won't support GPT, or EFI/UEFI

Ideally GPT is your is the newer and better choice.

Booting with GPT is only supported for 64 bit editions on EFI/UEFI-based system.

Windows should detect and handle EFI, but you need the 64 bit version of windows.

Windows 7 Should automatically load EFi/UEFI automatically if support is detected.

If doesn't.

1. Back up all data to another drive.
2. Boot the windows 7 installer
3. Shift F8 should get you a command prompt
4. diskpart
5. select disk 0
6. clean (all partition and data on said disk are lost)
7. convert GPT
8. exit
9. Continue with the installer normally.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/375785/windows-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-gpt provides greater clarity on the subject. 32 bit Win7 requires the legacy mode to boot, and therefore MBR.

Comment: Fortunately,, DISKPART allows you to convert a disk from MBR to GPT or vice versa as illustrated at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-installing-using-the-mbr-or-gpt-partition-style and https://www.disk-partition.com/windows-7/how-to-install-windows-7-on-gpt-partition-style-3889.html

Comment: If you are recommending g a UEFI install then you should specify what options need to be chosen to do that like the poster asked.